# Q: Comparision of specified points in two images in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, image-processing, video-processing, matlab-cvst

I have to write an application, which is tracking an chosen object in a video. 
Next i have to open a second video, choose an element i want to track.
I want to compare these 2 objects, and if it turns out that these objects are the same my program become tracking this object, and if it's not, program is displaying proper message.

And there is a problem; **how can i compare these 2 objects?**

here is the program code, all i have to add is 'if' statement, in which object is recognized.

whole method i took from this tutorial:
http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/examples/face-detection-and-tracking-using-the-klt-algorithm.html

```
clear;
PrzestRobocza1 = vision.VideoFileReader('2.avi');                                 
Odtwarzacz1 = vision.VideoPlayer('Position', [125, 125, 700, 540]);                 
PierwszaKlatka1= step(PrzestRobocza1);                                                 

figure;
imshow(PierwszaKlatka1);
title('Zaznacz obszar na ktorym znajduje sie sledzony obiekt');
ObszarObiektu1= round(getPosition(imrect)); 
imwrite(ObszarObiektu1, 'abcdcd.jpg');
PunktyChar1 = detectMinEigenFeatures(rgb2gray(PierwszaKlatka1), 'ROI',           ObszarObiektu1);   
PokazPunkty1 = insertMarker(PierwszaKlatka1, PunktyChar1.Location, 'o',   'Color', 'green');


figure; 
imshow(PokazPunkty1);
title('Punkty charakterystyczne na obszarze');

Sledzenie1 = vision.PointTracker('MaxBidirectionalError', 1);
initialize(Sledzenie1, PunktyChar1.Location, PierwszaKlatka1);

while ~isDone(PrzestRobocza1)
      Ramka1 = step(PrzestRobocza1);
      [PunktyChar1, validity] = step(Sledzenie1, Ramka1);
      out = insertMarker(Ramka1, PunktyChar1(validity, :), 'o');
      step(Odtwarzacz1, out);
end

release(Odtwarzacz1);
release(PrzestRobocza1);

PrzestRobocza2 = vision.VideoFileReader('3.avi');                                
Odtwarzacz2 = vision.VideoPlayer('Position', [125, 125, 700, 540]);             
PierwszaKlatka2 = step(PrzestRobocza2);
figure;
imshow(PierwszaKlatka2);
title('Zaznacz obszar na ktorym znajduje sie sledzony obiekt');
ObszarObiektu2= round(getPosition(imrect)); 
imwrite(ObszarObiektu2, 'zdj1.jpg');
%pobieranie współrzędnych śledzonego obiektu
PunktyChar2 = detectMinEigenFeatures(rgb2gray(PierwszaKlatka2), 'ROI',     ObszarObiektu2);  
PokazPunkty2 = insertMarker(PierwszaKlatka2, PunktyChar2.Location, '+', 'Color', 'red');
figure; 
imshow(PokazPunkty2);
title('Punkty charakterystyczne na obszarze');



if    %here is the problematic statement

    Sledzenie2 = vision.PointTracker('MaxBidirectionalError', 1);
        initialize(Sledzenie2, PunktyChar2.Location, PierwszaKlatka1); 

        while ~isDone(PrzestRobocza2)
            Ramka1 = step(PrzestRobocza2);
            [PunktyChar2, validity] = step(Sledzenie2, Ramka2);
            out = insertMarker(Ramka2, PunktyChar2(validity, :), 'o');
            step(Odtwarzacz2, out);
    end

        release(Odtwarzacz2);
        release(PrzestRobocza2);
   else                            
        disp('brak dopasowania!');
    end
```

Comment: It's not as easy as adding an `if` statement. It is a difficult problem. People spend years on it. I think you have quite a bit of reading to do on how to compare objects first...

Comment: What kind of object are you using? There are a lot of ways to check if an object is similar to other, and the problem relies in what object you are using, here some examples: [finger print recognition](http://fingerchip.pagesperso-orange.fr/biometrics/types/fingerprint_algo.htm) needs to extract some feature points after this extraction some distances in the feature points are computed and if some of these distances match with other previous distances in a data base both objects are the same, and this is not the only approach but this suit this application. Are you searching faces?